# Moving the scrolling bar up or down

Tags: jquery, css

As i was going through extjs examples i came across this behavior http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/array-grid.html

When you click on a row and as you begin moving the cursor up or down,the scrolling bar moves along and when you arrive at the last record,the scrolling bar is down there with you.

The example is using some keyboard events but in my example,i am attempting just a highlight to the row and hopefully i will understand how that is done.

This is my example http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/phEax/

This is how i got my scrolling bars

```
.tableholder{border:2px solid red; overflow-y:auto;height:300px}
```

What is making the scrolling bars move along as you move up or down the rows?.

Comment: Doesn't auto scroll for me. Am I missing something? Ah do you mean using arrow keys on keyboard?

Comment: Click on a row, then push your keyboard down arrow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Checkout this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phEax/2/). It uses following code in addition to your code to mimic a very basic version of table control you're aiming for

```
        var cntnr = $('.tableholder');
        var cntnr_height = cntnr.height();
        var cntnr_top = cntnr.offset().top;
        var cntnr_scrolltop = cntnr.scrollTop();
        var all_rows = $('tr', cntnr)
        var row_height = $(all_rows.get(0)).height();

        $('.tableholder').click(function (ev) {
           var t = ev.target;
           if (t.tagName != 'TD' && t.tagName != 'TR')
              return;

           var the_row = t.tagName == 'TR' ? $(t) : $(t.parentNode)
           all_rows.removeClass('current')
           the_row.addClass('current');
        })

        $('#deselect').click(function () {
           all_rows.removeClass('current');
        })

        $(document).click(function (ev) {
           /*if ($(ev.target) != cntnr && $(ev.target).parents().filter(cntnr).length == 0 && $(ev.target).hasClass('container'))
            all_rows.removeClass('current');*/
        }).keydown(function (ev) {

              //don't scroll if no rows are selected
              if (all_rows.filter('.current').length == 0) {
                 return;
              }

              var keycode = ev.which;

              if ([38, 40].indexOf(keycode) !== -1) {
                 ev.preventDefault();
              }
              else {
                 //we only scroll on up/down arrow
                 return;
              }

              var the_row = all_rows.filter('.current');
              var next = the_row.next();
              var prev = the_row.prev();

              //check if reached extremes of table
              if (
                 keycode == 40 && !next.length
                    || keycode == 38 && !prev.length
                 )
                 return false;

              the_row.removeClass('current');

              if (keycode == 40) {
                 if (next.offset().top + row_height + 10 - cntnr_top > cntnr_height + cntnr.scrollTop()) {
                    cntnr.scrollTop(cntnr.scrollTop() + row_height);
                 }
                 next.addClass('current');
                 setDataFromRow(next)
              }
              else {
                 if (prev.offset().top < cntnr.scrollTop()) {
                    cntnr.scrollTop(cntnr.scrollTop() - row_height);
                 }
                 prev.addClass('current');
                 setDataFromRow(prev)
              }
           });

        function setDataFromRow(row) {
           if (!row instanceof jQuery)
              row = $(row)

           ip_id.val($('td:nth-child(1)', row).html());
           ip_firstname.val($('td:nth-child(2)', row).html());
           ip_lastname.val($('td:nth-child(3)', row).html());
           ip_country.val($('td:nth-child(4)', row).html());
           ip_city.val($('td:nth-child(5)', row).html());
           ip_town.val($('td:nth-child(6)', row).html());
           ip_gender.val($('td:nth-child(7)', row).html());

        }

        var curr = $("tr").eq(1);
        curr.addClass("current");

        /*$('#id').val('0');
         $('#firstname').val('firstname');
         $('#lastname').val('lastname');
         $('#country').val('country');
         $('#city').val('city');
         $('#town').val('town');
         $('#gender').val('gender');*/

        var ip_id = $('#id'),
           ip_firstname = $('#firstname'),
           ip_lastname = $('#lastname'),
           ip_country = $('#country'),
           ip_city = $('#city'),
           ip_town = $('#town'),
           ip_gender = $('#gender');


        setDataFromRow(curr);

        /* your event handlers for buttons here  */
```

Please note that this code might not be perfect in all ways. I havn't touched your event handling code that goes wrong at some points :D I hope you get a starting point and a direction from this code

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/Memolition/DcaG4/

```
$('table tr').click(function() {
    var now_index = $(this).index();
    $('table tr').removeClass('back_change');
    $(this).addClass('back_change');
});
$(document).keydown(function(event){
    var keycode=(event.keyCode?event.keyCode:event.which);
     if(keycode == '40') {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('table tr.back_change').removeClass('back_change').next().addClass('back_change');
        $('div').animate({
         scrollTop: $('table tr.back_change').offset().top
     }, 2000);
    }
});
$(document).keydown(function(event){
    var keycode=(event.keyCode?event.keyCode:event.which);
    if(keycode == '38') {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('table tr.back_change').removeClass('back_change').prev().addClass('back_change');
        $('div').animate({
         scrollTop: $('table tr.back_change').offset().top
     }, 100);
   }
});
```